# Firemonkey Delphi XE3: Strange Issue for a TGlowEffect on Mouse Over

Tags: xcode, macos, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I got a little strange issue for my Firemonkey Delphi XE3 project, I tested the app on OSX 10.8.3.

Normally when mouse cursor move over the text, it looks:

[image]

But after the app call to open a Standard Dialog box, then I move the mouse cursor over the text again, it look like this:

[image]

I suspect the issue is due to Retina display, since my friend tested it on non-retina mac, it looks ok, my macbook support retina and I got this issue..

Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: It could be a Bug in XE3. Have you tested it with XE4? If the results are the same - don't hesitate to post a bug report at QC ;)

Comment: Not sure, but it must be caused by the mouse over effect.. when I connect my macbook to 27' monitor, no issue, when I connect to another 22' monitor, issue show up... strange.. I don't have XE4, so can't test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This such 'bug' is actually related to the changes made in FM2 (You mention XE3/FM2, but the question is tagged as XE2/FMX) but it also sometimes occurred in FMX applications. The solution is to simply call the `repaint()` function on the label. I'm going to assume `ShowMessage` for the sake of simplicity, but the same applies whenever you deal with anything in the UI (message boxes, panels, vector shapes, etc).

```
ShowMessage('My Message');
Label1.Repaint;
```

Using repaint() should be something you make use of when appropriate. It is a heavy operation (generally speaking), and you should use it liberally. General guidelines;

- Only use it when necessary
- If you need to repaint just 1 child component, only repaint that component
- If you need to repaint many child components, repaint the parent component instead
- Repaint should be used on parent component of effects instead of the effect itself (i.e. on the `TLabel` instead of the `TGlowEffect`)

I've actually resorted to putting my entire application's interface inside a TLayout or TRectangle with a colour of claNull. This way, I can repaint the entire interface in one call. I then separate the individual major parts out into child TLayouts (such as an alert bar), and then can opt to repaint that on a timer if I need to animate it (e.g. sliding into view when there's a new message).